# How to make if condition true only when variable changes to certain value

Tags: c, if-statement

Let's consider the following program:

```
while(1)
{
  if(foo1 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
  }
  if(foo2 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo2 is high");
  }
}
```

As these conditions are in `while(1)` loop when `foo1` is HIGH `printf` will keep on printing until `foo1` is LOW and the same goes for `foo2`.

Is there any possible way I can only print when the condition becomes true and not continuously? Also when `foo1` has gone to LOW and becomes HIGH again the if condition should be true again.

**EDIT**

using flags to check condition will not work here because

```
bool check = false;
while(1)
if(foo1 == HIGH && check == false)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
    check = true;
  }
```

this will just make it run once. But lets say after some time if `foo1` becomes HIGH again then the if condition will not be executed because check is still true as `bool check` is defined outside `while(1)`. If we define it inside `while(1)`, then if condition will keep on going as check will be set to false each time.

Comment: Just set foo1 to low after the printf? Am i missing something here? If you cannot change foo1, just have another variable foo1printed, set that one true after the printf.

Comment: @Amit cannot remove while, program needs to check continuously for the status of foo

Comment: @HugoRune didn't get you, if you are talking about using flags, then it won't work here.! or if you can give me demo

Comment: @user9999 See my answer, it will print the message every time foo1 becomes HIGH, not only once and doesn't change the variables.

Comment: @user9999 Hope my edit made your question more clear, if it didn't please roll back and/or edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to remember that you've already displayed the message. You can use boolean variables for that. Something like:

```
bool foo1MsgDisplayed = false;
bool foo2MsgDisplayed = false;

while(1) {
  if(foo1 == HIGH && !foo1MsgDisplayed) {
    printf("foo1 is high");
    foo1MsgDisplayed = true;
  }
  if(foo2 == HIGH && !foo2MsgDisplayed) {
    printf("foo2 is high");
    foo2MsgDisplayed = true;
  }
}
```

**EDIT** Based on your comments, it seems you want to reset the flags when `foo` changes to low:

```
bool foo1MsgDisplayed = false;
bool foo2MsgDisplayed = false;

while(1) {
  if(foo1 == HIGH) {
    if(!foo1MsgDisplayed) {
      printf("foo1 is high");
      foo1MsgDisplayed = true;
    }
  }
  else {
    foo1MsgDisplayed = false;
  }

  if(foo2 == HIGH) {
    if(!foo2MsgDisplayed) {
      printf("foo2 is high");
      foo2MsgDisplayed = true;
    }
  else {
    foo2MsgDisplayed = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should work but dont know why its not working. Printf is keep on displaying message.!

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure you typed the conditions right? I mean `if(!foo1MsgDisplayed)` not `if(foo1MsgDisplayed)`... I cannot find a reason why it won't work.

Comment: yes I typed it correct. I think the condition which I am thinking cannot be fulfilled.!

Comment: What condition cannot be fulfilled? Do you have more related code than what you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I think there is some problem with the hardware I am testing because I have tested your code in debugging mode and it looks like my hardware has got some problem. I am accepting your answer because your approach is different and I know it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers already posted assume you can change the variables or you only want to display the message once. What I understand is every time foo1 *becomes HIGH* you want to display the message. Therefore the general issue is *detecting change* not *remembering if message has been shown*.

You just need to remember the previous value for that to happen.

```
int prevfoo1 = LOW;

while(1)
{
  if (prevfoo1 != foo1)
  {
    if (foo1 == HIGH)
      printf("foo1 is high");
    prevfoo1 = foo1;
  }
}
```

This way every time foo1 becomes HIGH you will get the notification. You can also use this for general change detection since we don't store booleans but the actual previous value.

Comment: you answer is same as Rachil. I want printf to run once but its kepp on going.!

Comment: It is not the same and it will not keep on going. You have an error in your implementation if it does, since the `prevfoo1` is clearly set to `foo1` so it can't be different from `foo1` if `foo1` keeps its value. Paste the actual code you're running here.

Comment: It's a nice approach. However, the end results for this particular question are the same. I'd use your approach if there were more state conditions, but in this question there is only one condition, so both approaches are OK.

Comment: @RacilHilan Yes, both work for this case, there is only the nuance difference in what is being monitored.

Comment: yes i think there is some other problem i guess. This looks like to be impossible

Comment: @user9999 are you using some kind of hardware card with buttons so that each button press the signal (gliches) goes HIGH LOW HIGH LOW and so on until it gets stable? This is the only reason why you might think that this code would not work as expected....

Comment: I am using hardware but not the switches, maybe there is some problem in the hardware. I am so sorry for that.!

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the loop with `break`

You can put a check variable

```
 bool check1 = false;
 bool check2 = false;
```

Then check in loop if it has been printed.

E.g.

```
 if( foo1 == HIGH && check1 == false )
 {
     check1 = true;
     printf( "foo1 is high");
 }
```

If latching behaviour, then maybe...

```
 if( foo1 == HIGH && check1 == false )
 {
     check1 = true;
     printf( "foo1 is high");
 }
 else if( foo1 != HIGH )
 {
     check1 = false;
 }
```

Comment: where can i define bool check1 = false?

Comment: the problem is if check1 becomes true then when foo1 again becomes high later after few sec then printf will not be executed again.!

Comment: Maybe edit your question.  The guard check1 implements when it is acceptable to print again.   This can be set to false if needed.

Comment: yes you are right. But lets say if I define bool check1 = false; outside while(1) so if foo1 becomes high again, then it wont execute if condition because check1 is set true.
and if we define bool check1 = false; inside while(1) then it will keep on displaying printf as condition will match everytime

Answer (score 0):

Loops are used to run anything repeatedly several times. If you want it to run just once, you no need that loop at all. You can give those particular lines of codes outside while.
If you want it to be inside for some reasons, you can use a bool variable to see if it is already executed and break the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you really need this infinite loop

```
while(1)
{
  if(foo1 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
  }
  if(foo2 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo2 is high");
  }
}
```

You can just reset `foo1` and `foo2` to different than HIGH values inside their `if` statements.

```
while(1)
{
  if(foo1 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
    foo1 = LOW;
  }
  if(foo2 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo2 is high");
    foo2 = LOW;
  }
}
```

If this is not the full code and the `while` loop contains more code that can modify `foo1` and `foo2` then a flag that would indicate if the condition was TRUE can help:

```
bool foo1_flag = false;
bool foo2_flag = false;

while(1)
{
  if(!foo1_flag && foo1 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
    foo1_flag = true;
  }
  if(!foo2_flag && foo2 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo2 is high");
    foo2_flag = true;
  }
}
```

**Edit**

If you need the `printf` to work once the foo becomes LOW and then HIGH again you need to reset the flags (which is not what you originally asked)

```
bool foo1_flag = false;
bool foo2_flag = false;

while(1)
{
  if(!foo1_flag && foo1 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
    foo1_flag = true;
  }
  else if (foo1_flag && foo1 != HIGH)
  {
    foo1_flag = false;
  }
  if(!foo2_flag && foo2 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo2 is high");
    foo2_flag = true;
  }
  else if (foo2_flag && foo2 != HIGH)
  {
    foo2_flag = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: as I said in comments to mksteve answer. when if condition runs for the first time foo1_flag becomes true so printf will be displayed just once. But again after few seconds, if foo1 becomes high again, then as foo1_flag1 is set to true the if condition will not run because bool foo1_flag = false; is defined outside while(1), so it wont work

Comment: @user9999 but you asked to cause the  `printf` run once. So won't it work?

Comment: it will work for the first time but what if foo1 becomes high again, then it wont work.!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are doing something else inside the loop. In which case the cleanest approach is to move the code to be performed exactly once to be before the loop:

```
if(foo1 == HIGH)
{
  printf("foo1 is high");
}
if(foo2 == HIGH)
{
  printf("foo2 is high");
}
while(1)
{
  // do whatever needs to be done repeatedly
}
```

Comment: I need to check for the foo1 status everytime so putting it outside while(1) will not work.!

Comment: Not according to the question that I answered. How can those variables change? There is no code that modifies them. Would it seem rude for me to suggest that you asked the wrong question? Please try harder to define your requirements before asking.

Comment: maybe I have not described my question properly.! its okay.

Comment: It's not really OK. We just waste our time because you didn't think hard enough. Instead of you spending time to ask the right question, we all waste our time. My advice to you is to think harder before you ask. Try to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

Split the while into two whiles...

```
while(foo1 == HIGH)
{  
    printf("foo1 is high");
}

while(foo2 == HIGH)
{
    printf("foo2 is high");
}
```

or

put the two whiles inside the main while

```
while(1)
{
    while(foo1 == HIGH)
    {  
        printf("foo1 is high");
    }

    while(foo2 == HIGH)
    {
        printf("foo2 is high");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not show the message once, this will continue to show it forever and if it's a single threaded program the variables can never even change states.

Comment: I didn't see the OP's edit as I was writing this it hadn't been there yet ;-]

Comment: but dont you think while will also keep on displaying the printf again and again till the foo1 is high or foo2

Comment: Well, you question wasn't very clear at first, so you shouldn't expect perfect answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following and remember the old value of foo and only print if it has changed since the last execution.

```
Type oldFoo1 = null / -1;
Type oldFoo2 = null / -1;

while(1) {
  if(oldFoo1 != foo1 && foo1 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo1 is high");
  }
  if(oldFoo2 != foo2 && foo2 == HIGH)
  {
    printf("foo2 is high");
  }
  oldFoo1 = foo1;
  oldFoo2 = foo2;
}
```